# Play square wave SciPy and PyAudio

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pyaudio

I'm trying to play square waves generated using SciPy with PyAudio but I get the error

> TypeError: len() of unsized object

which is kind of strange because the square wave object should have a size, right?

```
RATE = 48000
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format = pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels = 2,
            rate = RATE,
            output = True)
# ... inside a loop
    wav = signal.square(2*math.pi*FREQ*t)
    wav = wav.astype(np.int16)
    stream.write(wav) # crash here
```

The crash happens on the first iteration of the loop, so I suppose the loop is not a problem.

Comment: Can you post more parts of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same error. However, you are omitting some information, so I will assume these are your imports:

```
import pyaudio
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
```

And that

```
FREQ = 440
```

It looks like the variable you are iterating is `t` and it's a scalar. You might have good reasons to do this, but I don't think it is how `scipy.signal` is meant to work. If you use a vector `t` instead:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 2)
```

Then `signal.square(...)` and `stream.write(wav.astype(np.int16))` work without problems.